# DB File Closes After One Statement Execution with TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I understand from other posts that with this error, I can't assign a value that doesn't exist. But I'm wondering why sqlite/python behaves this way as I'm trying to get conditions to pass:

```
  1 import sqlite3
  2 
  3 conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
  4 
  5 username = input("Username: ")
  6 
  7 rows = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username", [username])
  8 
  9 print(len(rows.fetchall()))
 10 
 11 pwhash = rows.fetchone()[2]
 12 print(pwhash)
 13
```

If I execute the code above and input Alice/alice(which exists in the database), I'd get:

```
username: alice
1
pwhash = rows.fetchone()[2]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Now if I swap the positions between pwhash and print(pwhash) with len(rows.fetchall()) statements, I'd get:

```
username:alice
pbkdf2:sha256:150000$aZgmxaja$5a6f6cec4cac11ba7d330a69c5f2f7f198172c27a12a75c96abe61d04e213e51                                                         
0
```

The output would successfully displays Alice's password hash value but displays print(len(rows.fetchall())) as `0` (as if it did not find the row that it found a second ago) instead of `1`. It seems to me that the db file closes after one statement execution and causes the remaining variables unable to get the value from the database.

The desired result:

```
username:alice
1
pbkdf2:sha256:150000$aZgmxaja$5a6f6cec4cac11ba7d330a69c5f2f7f198172c27a12a75c96abe61d04e213e51
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with:

```
  1 import sqlite3
  2 
  3 conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
  4 
  5 username = input("Username: ")
  6 
  7 rows = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :username", [username]).fetchall()
  8 
  9 pwhash = rows[0][2]
 10 
 11 print(len(rows)
 12 print(pwhash)
 13
```

and finally got:

```
username:alice
1
pbkdf2:sha256:150000$aZgmxaja$5a6f6cec4cac11ba7d330a69c5f2f7f198172c27a12a75c96abe61d04e213e51
```

Reason being: calling fetch function after another results in trying to fetch the next non-existing row.